# After Upgrade from 1.4 to 1.9.1 getting undefined method Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare::setCustomerId

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-1.4

I am Getting the error 
Call to undefined method Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare::setCustomerId()
After Upgrading From Magento 1.4 to 1.9.1

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

boussema and welcome to MageOverflwo. This is unfortunately FAR to less information. You should at least provide a stacktrace.

But in 1.9.1 the method exists, so maybe you didn't upgrade all files?

```
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Helper/Product/Compare.php:312
\Mage_Catalog_Helper_Product_Compare::setCustomerId
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but That's all what I ve got when exception was thrown.

Comment: Then you need to learn how to debug magento: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store